# Send login credentials to another server

Tags: django, encryption, rsa, pycrypto

I have two servers running django.  I'll call one server my "logging" server and another my "client" server.  The client server wants to log a message with the logging server by passing over a username, password, and message over the internet.  With my current implementation I'm hitting an error when trying to decrypt the encrypted message, username, and password that was sent over the wire.  It looks like I should be trying to decrypt a "byte string" according to the pycrypto documentation, but I can't seem to create a byte string correctly since I haven't been able to get around this problem.  Also, it feels like my implementation is taking me down a rabbit hole of security vulnerabilities and codec confusion.  Is there a package that I should look at which already implements this type of functionality?  If so what would that implementation look like?

client:

```
from Crypto.Hash import MD5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from base64 import b64decode
import urllib2
import urllib

#I realize recreating the hash everytime is slow.  I just included it here for simplicity.
logger_public_signature_message = "I am a client :)"
logger_public_signature_hash = MD5.new(logger_public_signature_message).digest()

client_private_key = #private key
logger_public_key = #public key
client_private = RSA.importKey(client_private_key)
client_public = client_private.publickey()
logger_public = RSA.importKey(logger_public_key)

message = "my message"
username = "user"
password = "password"

encrypted_message = logger_public.encrypt(message, "ignored_param")
encrypted_username = logger_public.encrypt(username, "ignored_param")
encrypted_password = logger_public.encrypt(password, "ignored_param")
signature = client_private.sign(logger_public_signature_hash, '')

params = { "message": encrypted_message, "username": encrypted_username, "password": encrypted_password, "signature": signature }
url_encoded_params = urllib.urlencode(params)
url = 'http://localhost:8000/url/to/logger/'
req = urllib2.Request(url, url_encoded_params)
```

logger:

```
from Crypto.Hash import MD5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from base64 import b64decode

def log(request):
    #I realize recreating the hash everytime is slow.  I just included it here for simplicity.
    logger_public_signature_message = "I am a client :)"
    logger_public_signature_hash = MD5.new(logger_public_signature_message).digest()

    client_public_key = #client public key
    logger_private_key = #logger private key
    client_public = RSA.importKey(client_public_key)
    logger_private = RSA.importKey(logger_private_key)

    p = request.POST

    encrypted_message = urllib2.unquote(p["message"])
    encrypted_username = urllib2.unquote(p["username"])
    encrypted_password = urllib2.unquote(p["password"])
    signature = urllib2.unquote(p["signature"])


    #I'm hitting exceptions when trying to decrypt the encrypted messages.
    #The exceptions are: "ValueError: Message too large"  I think the issue is that
    #I'm trying to decrypt a base64 string where I should be trying to decrypt a byte
    #string from reading the documentation.  But I haven't been able I guess to correctly
    #create a byte string because I can't get it to work.
    decrypted_message = logger_private.decrypt(encrypted_message.encode("base64"))
    decrypted_username = logger_private.decrypt(encrypted_username.encode("base64"))
    decrypted_password = logger_private.decrypt(encrypted_password.encode("base64"))
    verified = client_public.verify(logger_public_signature_hash, signature)
```

Comment: I would first try [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html) module to solve problems like you are describing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are putting a lot of effort into stuff, that doesn't need to be handled by Django.

Here is what I would usually do:

1. Use HTTPS, as transport encryption layer
2. Use HTTP Basic Auth. Basic auth is implemented in `urllib2` as well as `requests`.

But there is an even better solution: [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication)

It provides you will a full blown REST API including different authentication solutions.

If you need any help, setting up one of these options, let me know and I'll add an example.

Answer (score 1):

May it be that you would use [sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry) for logging? Of course if it isn't task for training.

I look at the sentry since it been django application, and now it surely is excellent  production-ready solution.
We're using it in banking-sphere software development.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close to decrypting the values on the server. The result of the encryption on the client is a tuple. When you urllib2.unquote the items on the server, you then recreate tuples from them.

For example:

```
>>> c = public.encrypt('Hello', "ignored")
>>> c
('3\xae0\x1f\xd7\xe4b\xd4\xf1\xf4\x88!Be\xff!\x1e\xda\x82\x10\x9bRy\x0c\xa0v\xed\x84\xf9\xe35\xc6QG\xcf\xb7\x1b\xea\x9fe\t\x9b\x8d\xd6\xf3\x8cw\xde\x17\xb5\xf7\x9a+\x84i%@\x8a\xdf\xf4\xdd\xc8wY',)
```

which in your code you pack into params like this:

```
>>> params = { "message" : c }
>>> params
{'message': ('3\xae0\x1f\xd7\xe4b\xd4\xf1\xf4\x88!Be\xff!\x1e\xda\x82\x10\x9bRy\x0c\xa0v\xed\x84\xf9\xe35\xc6QG\xcf\xb7\x1b\xea\x9fe\t\x9b\x8d\xd6\xf3\x8cw\xde\x17\xb5\xf7\x9a+\x84i%@\x8a\xdf\xf4\xdd\xc8wY',)}
>>> urllib.urlencode(params)
'message=%28%273%5Cxae0%5Cx1f%5Cxd7%5Cxe4b%5Cxd4%5Cxf1%5Cxf4%5Cx88%21Be%5Cxff%21%5Cx1e%5Cxda%5Cx82%5Cx10%5Cx9bRy%5Cx0c%5Cxa0v%5Cxed%5Cx84%5Cxf9%5Cxe35%5Cxc6QG%5Cxcf%5Cxb7%5Cx1b%5Cxea%5Cx9fe%5Ct%5Cx9b%5Cx8d%5Cxd6%5Cxf3%5Cx8cw%5Cxde%5Cx17%5Cxb5%5Cxf7%5Cx9a%2B%5Cx84i%25%40%5Cx8a%5Cxdf%5Cxf4%5Cxdd%5Cxc8wY%27%2C%29'
```

I would guess that urllib2.unquote(p["message"]) returns this (but I did not try this):

```
"('3\\xae0\\x1f\\xd7\\xe4b\\xd4\\xf1\\xf4\\x88!Be\\xff!\\x1e\\xda\\x82\\x10\\x9bRy\\x0c\\xa0v\\xed\\x84\\xf9\\xe35\\xc6QG\\xcf\\xb7\\x1b\\xea\\x9fe\\t\\x9b\\x8d\\xd6\\xf3\\x8cw\\xde\\x17\\xb5\\xf7\\x9a+\\x84i%@\\x8a\\xdf\\xf4\\xdd\\xc8wY',)"
```

then you can recreate the tuple at the server like this (m is the unquoted message):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval(m)
('3\xae0\x1f\xd7\xe4b\xd4\xf1\xf4\x88!Be\xff!\x1e\xda\x82\x10\x9bRy\x0c\xa0v\xed\x84\xf9\xe35\xc6QG\xcf\xb7\x1b\xea\x9fe\t\x9b\x8d\xd6\xf3\x8cw\xde\x17\xb5\xf7\x9a+\x84i%@\x8a\xdf\xf4\xdd\xc8wY',)
```

once you have the tuple back, you can decrypt it:

```
>>> private.decrypt(literal_eval(m))
'Hello'
```

It would be better to find a vetted and standard mechanism to do this rather than roll your own. For example, in your scheme, I could capture different messages between the client and server, and then mix and match messages and username/password pairs, making it appear that the messages came from different users.

However, with just this minor tweak (recreating the tuples from the "unquoted" strings) your code should decrypt just fine.